# Is there any eclipse plugin available for React JS

Tags: eclipse, reactjs

I am planning to use React JS with Rest API But after spending long time on google cant find the best way to start. There are no eclipse plugins available for react js. Please suggest how i can start working on React with eclipse or other open source editors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i had the same issue and ended up to use the atom editor: https://atom.io/
Atom is based on google chrome, but you will not feel using google chrome, but a full featured editor with many cool plugins available.

I know, there is a nodeeclipse project http://www.nodeclipse.org/ but i was not able to install and run it out-of-the-box and it seems that jsx syntax for ES6 was not supported.

Now i really like atom editor, it is very easy to handle. Of course some shortcuts are different compared to eclipse, but anyway, i was really quickly able to produce code.
atom seems to be pretty lightweight and does not eat so much memory like eclipse. So there is no problem developing your reactjs app in atom and have eclipse as second editor running developing your rest app.

Kind regards

davey

Comment: is Atom is open source?

Comment: yes, atom is open source, according to their message on their homepage: https://atom.io/:

"Atom is open source. "

Comment: There is actually a plugin to support JSX and typescript in Eclipse. It's called "TypeScript" and it's provided by Palantir.

Comment: I do not like atom on the other hand, but who am I to judge

Comment: @pstanton it depends on your criteria but I'm satisfied with it ;)

Answer (score 7):

Genuitec has an Eclipse plugin called [CodeMix](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/codemix) that provides wizards, navigation, content assist, validation, and debugging for ReactJS in Eclipse. You can details for all the features that CodeMix provides for for React development [on the Genuitec website](https://www.genuitec.com/tech/react-in-eclipse/).

Answer (score 1):

Angelo Zerr's TypeScript IDE includes a JSX editor and provides some support. Search for it in the Eclipse Marketplace Client or go to https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/typescript-ide

Answer (score 0):

I use vim. Plenty support on syntax highlighting on JSX, ES6. auto formatting, unit test running, etc. There are plenty of vim configurations you can find on github so you can get a quick start. An example of mine: https://github.com/ywen/vim-config-files

Answer (score 0):

There is not a proper plugin for eclipse, you can use [codemix](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/react-codemix) but the code completion are not proper and it is quite slower but for as if now that is the best for eclipse. Use VS code that is the best .

You can not directly install codemix plugin from marketplace, by drag n drop or by marketplace. To install codemix please follow the below steps:

In ECLIPSE or STS

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]